# Sanctum unauthentication message

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum, laravel-api

In my project I use Fortify for login, registration, password reset and Sanctum which help me with api Authentication.

All Fortify routes work fine(login, password confirmation routes).

But after successfully login, when I want use protected route in api routes file laravel return me:

> Message : unauthenticated

My route has included :

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')
```

P.s.
I use Postman

Where is my fault?
What should I do?

Comment: you have to pass the token via the Authorization header with the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

My query included all cookies and a token. In my inquiries, I had to add header:

```
Origin : 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Because in

> vendor\laravel\sanctum\src\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful.php

I reed this:

> $domain = $request->headers->get('referer') ?: $request->headers->get('origin');

Comment: Nice find! I was also stuck at this for a long time. Didn't see it mentioned in the docs anywhere. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: To make it funnier, I created a new project today. I had the same problem again. Two hours later I found my own post in stack. Thank myself